# Xcode ⌃d EOF Not Working After Paste

Tags: c, xcode, eof

Behavior is very inconsistent-- very frustrating.

The problem must lie in pasting some input text into Xcode's Debug Area.

Here's how to replicate the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main() {
int c, i, nwhite, nother;
int ndigit[10];
nwhite = nother = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    ndigit[i] = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        ++ndigit[c-'0'];
    else if (c==' '||c=='\n'||c=='\t')
        ++nwhite;
    else
        ++nother;
printf("digits =");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

1. Run this C code in Xcode
2. Paste in some Lorem Ipsum into Xcode Debugger Area
3. ⌃d will not send EOF signal

Doesn't work even if you send Ctrl-d on its own line.

Note** Works fine (pasting in lipsum and signaling EOF with ⌃d) when you run the compiled executable from Terminal. Also, Ctrl-d doesn't need to be on its own line (just keystroked twice in a row). Still works regardless.

Comment: So does `Ctrl-D` work *at all* within the Xcode debugging window (i.e even without pasting text first)?

Comment: Yes! Ctrl-D works as it should and sends the EOF signal if input text is typed into the debugger.